# Python issue when returning function from another file

Tags: python, return

I'm having a bit of an issue when trying to return a function from another file.

main.py:

```
from master_input import load_input

class Vera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        masterinput = load_input()
        self.masterinput = masterinput

    def load_masterinput(self):
        return self.masterinput
```

master_input.py:

```
import sys

def load_input():
    if sys.version_info <= (3,0,0):
        masterinput = raw_input()
    elif sys.version_info >= (2,7,11):
        masterinput = input()
    return masterinput
```

There seems to be no output when running the first file. I want it to return `masterinput` in the second file because if I were to end the function with `load_input()`, in the second file, it would just output without even returning `self.masterinput` in the first file.

Comment: We'll need more detail about your file structure, I think.  The code as posted doesn't quite run: core.brain.master_input doesn't exist.  Since I have code that regularly returns functional results from another file, I do know that this works in general.  More description and example, please?

Answer (score 2):

You don't show an example of instantiated one of the **Vera()** options nor to you show any methods that would be using (displaying/printing or otherwise manipulating) this **masterinput** attribute of your **Veta()** instance.

So it seems quite likely that your code doesn't seem to be "doing" anything. You'd declared what the objects look like, how to instantiate them and how to respond to a (poorly named) *load_masterinput()* method call.

Also your module isn't returning a function. When an object is instantiated it, that could will be returning a string, the result of calling either the *input()* or *raw_input()* built-in function.

By the way, the smart way, in my opinion, to handle the change from Python2.x *raw_input()* to Python3 *input()* is to use code like this:

```
#!python
if 'raw_input' in dir(__builtins__):
    input = raw_input
```

Note that I'm assigning the function *raw_input* to the name *input* ... I'm NOT calling the function and assigning the results of its evaluation here.

Then all my code can use *input()* and we can forget that the Python2 (evaluated) *input()* semantics ever existed.

If I want to actually return a function from a function here's one way to do so:

```
#!python
# filename: my_input.py
def get_input_function():
    if 'raw_input' in dir(__builtins__):
        # Python2.x and earlier
        return raw_input
    else:
        # Python3
        return input
```

... I would then call this something like so:

```
#!python
import my_input
input = my_input.get_input_function()
```

This is unnecessarily obtuse.  There's no reason to do something like this for something so trivial.  There are cases where you might imagine calling some function, with certain arguments and returning different functions based on those arguments.  However, in most cases, you'd still be better off creating a ***class*** and instantiating an instance of that.

Comment: Is there a way to use `input` throughout files. For example, in the `main.py` file I have listed above, I'm trying to parse user inputs but I want to use the correct `input`. Thats why I have `master_input.py` file for.

Comment: Just as you've tried to do with your "master_input.py" ... you define your functions, classes and variables in some file, then you use the **import** statement to make all that you've defined available from within your other code.  You can also use the **from ____ import ____** variant of the import statement to merge items from your module directly into your code's top level name space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't actually returning the functions, but are instead calling the functions and returning the result.  Just remove the parentheses to change the function calls into the functions themselves.  I.e., change:

```
return func()
```

to:

```
return func
```

The return value will then be a callable function.